# How to sort by a field-sum of a subdocument

Tags: mongodb, meteor, aggregation-framework

... and reduce the subdocuments by a filter criterium?

I´ve got the following data-structure

```
{
    "_id" : "PwS8gcfhaWLaudjaJ",
    "name" : "Name of Document 1",
    "subdocuments" : [ 
        {
            "subdocumentsId" : "dqR9gPi7tNvzpEhEW",
            "number" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "subdocumentsId" : "vTaPoQYdaDbqMH7Pg",
            "number" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "subdocumentsId" : "tPJ45KqAzvFPBRstZ",
            "number" : 3
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : "PwS8gcfhaWLaudjaJ",
    "name" : "Name of Document 2",
    "subdocuments" : [ 
        {
            "subdocumentsId" : "dqR9gPi7tNvzpEhEW",
            "number" : 2
        }, 
        {
            "subdocumentsId" : "tPJ45KqAzvFPBRstZ",
            "number" : 5
        }
    ]
}
```

How to construct a query to get the below result

```
{
    "_id" : "PwS8gcfhaWLaudjaJ",
    "name" : "Name of Document 2",
    "subdocuments" : [ 
        {
            "subdocumentsId" : "dqR9gPi7tNvzpEhEW",
            "number" : 2
        }, 
        {
            "subdocumentsId" : "tPJ45KqAzvFPBRstZ",
            "number" : 5
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : "PwS8gcfhaWLaudjaJ",
    "name" : "Name of Document 1",
    "subdocuments" : [ 
        {
            "subdocumentsId" : "dqR9gPi7tNvzpEhEW",
            "number" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "subdocumentsId" : "tPJ45KqAzvFPBRstZ",
            "number" : 3
        }
    ]
}
```

... and here is my current query

```
var filterIds = ['dqR9gPi7tNvzpEhEW','tPJ45KqAzvFPBRstZ'];

db.Documents
.aggregate([
{
    $match: {
        'subdocuments.subdocumentsId': {
            $in: filterIds
        }
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        _id: 1,
        name: 1,
        totalNumber: {
            $sum: '$subdocuments.number'
        }
    }
}, {
    $sort: {
        totalNumber: 1
    }
}
])
```

I cannot work with the $sum-expression in a $project-operation. It´s only available for $group.

Is there a common workaround, or is it possible to get the result with a $group?

Maybe someone can help, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) when working with arrays. Also you have two [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) operations here with a [**`$sort`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) in between:

```js
db.Documents.aggregate([
    // Select documents
    { "$match": {
        "subdocuments.subdocumentsId": {
            "$in": filterIds
        }
    }}, 

    // Denormalize array
    { "$unwind": "subdocuments" }

    // Filter array elements
    { "$match": {
        "subdocuments.subdocumentsId": {
            "$in": filterIds
        }
    }}, 

    // Get array sum      
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "name": "$name",
            "subId": "$subdocuments.subdocumentsId"
        },
        "number": { "$sum": "$subdocuments.number" }
     }},

     // Sort the results
     { "$sort": { "_id._id": 1, "number": 1 } },

     // Group back to documents
     { "$group": {
         "_id": "$_id._id",
         "name": { "$first": "$_id.name" },
         "subdocuments": { "$push": {
             "subdocumentsId": "$_id.subId",
             "number": "$number"
         }},
         "total": { "$sum": "$number" }
     }},

     // Sort at the end, decending for largest first
     { "$sort": { "total": -1 } }
])
```

That is if you are "summing" your filtered results by their uinique "subdocumentId" values where those values are not unique. If you are just filtering then reduce the steps:

```js
db.Documents.aggregate([
    // Select documents
    { "$match": {
        "subdocuments.subdocumentsId": {
            "$in": filterIds
        }
    }}, 

    // Denormalize array
    { "$unwind": "subdocuments" }

    // Filter array elements
    { "$match": {
        "subdocuments.subdocumentsId": {
            "$in": filterIds
        }
    }}, 

     // Group back to documents
     { "$group": {
         "_id": "$_id",
         "name": { "$first": "$name" },
         "subdocuments": {
            "$push": "$subdocuments"
         },
         "total": { "$sum": "$subdocuments.number" }
     }},

     // Sort at the end, decending for largest first
     { "$sort": { "total": -1 } }
])
```

Comment: So great, thank you very much! It´s totally what i was searching for.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below query :

Below are the steps followed to fetch the result :

1) unwind your subdocuments

2) keep only those documents which match the filter "filterIds
" criteria

3) group the documents based on the _id field and also keep the sum of "subdocuments.number" field so that we can sort based on that.

4) sort based on the "subdocuments.number" field (tot) in descending order.

5) finally project or diplay in the format which you need.

```
db.Documents.aggregate([
{
 $unwind:"$subdocuments"
},
{
 $match:{"subdocuments.subdocumentsId" : {"$in" : filterIds }}
},
{
 $group:{ _id : { id : "$_id", name :"$name" },  
          tot : { "$sum": "$subdocuments.number"} , 
          subdocuments : {"$push" :
                         {subdocumentsId:"$subdocuments.subdocumentsId", 
          number : "$subdocuments.number" } }  } },
{
 $sort:{tot : -1}
},
{
 $project:{_id:"$_id.id", name: "$_id.name", subdocuments:1}
}
]).pretty();
```

So the above query fetches you the desired result ( OUTPUT )  :

```
{
        "_id" : "PwS8gcfhaWLaudjaI",
        "subdocuments" : [
                {
                        "subdocumentsId" : "dqR9gPi7tNvzpEhEW",
                        "number" : 2
                },
                {
                        "subdocumentsId" : "tPJ45KqAzvFPBRstZ",
                        "number" : 5
                }
        ],
        "name" : "Name of Document 2"
}
{
        "_id" : "PwS8gcfhaWLaudjaJ",
        "subdocuments" : [
                {
                        "subdocumentsId" : "dqR9gPi7tNvzpEhEW",
                        "number" : 1
                },
                {
                        "subdocumentsId" : "tPJ45KqAzvFPBRstZ",
                        "number" : 3
                }
        ],
        "name" : "Name of Document 1"
}
```

Comment: Big thanks to you, the aggregation-part is just awesome!